# Dynamic summing of n columns in SAS using arrays

Tags: sas, dynamic-arrays

I have a problem in SAS where I have to sum n columns(Time(1) to time(N)) where the N is defined as a variable in another column(Min_Remain_wthdrw_Prd). 
I am writing the below code but it is not working:

```
data certain;set certain;
array t(*) t1-t60;

do while(i<=Min_Remain_wthdrw_Prd);
S_Disc=sum(t(1)-t(i));
end;
end;
run;
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 3):

You have too many `end` statements, and you can just use a regular `do` loop...

```
data certain ;
  set certain ;
  array t(*) t1-t60 ;

  S_Disc = 0 ;
  do i = 1 to Min_Remain_wthdrw_Prd ;
    S_Disc+t{i} ;
  end ;
run;
```